# How to concatenate a char * and a const char*?

Tags: c++, c

I need to put "Hello World" in str3. How can I do this ?

```
const char *one = "Hello ";
char *two = "World";
char *str3;
```

Comment: str3 is just a pointer, you must allocate space for str3.

Comment: Or get a good book or tutorial. When you try that out and you've issues, come here.

Comment: `str3 = malloc(somenumber);strcpy(str3, one); strcat(str3, two);`

Comment: Now this is the kind of question for which I'm missing the "Must show minimal understanding" close reason.

Comment: Wow, seriosuly guys, answering for rep?!? Shouldn't we close this as a dupe?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks things which are essential for the language and can be read up in a good tutorial.

Comment: `char *str3 = strcat(strcpy(malloc(strlen(one)+strlen(two) + 1), one), two);
`

Comment: @legends2k Feel free to find a duplicate. Until then, this is a perfectly fine question, as far as SO posting policies are concerned.

Comment: Found quite sometime back, feel free to vote to close :P And this shows the difference between following a rule vs following the spirit of the rule.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY very nice. one liner in C :)..

Answer (score 7):

You have to allocate [`void* malloc (size_t size);`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) for str3 first then you can use [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/?kw=sprintf) to write in a string.

```
char *str3 = malloc(strlen(one) + strlen(two) + 1);
sprintf(str3, "%s%s", one, two);      //        ^  \0  termination
```

Adding @[Nik Bougalis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/970543/nik-bougalis) Suggestion:

One should know [dynamic memory allocation in C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation). In my code I allocated using `malloc()` so latter in code when I don't need `str3` we should explicitly deallocate memory  using [`free()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/) in C.

Also to avoid buffer-overflow always use [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) instead of `sprintf`: So re-writing code as follows:

```
int length = strlen(one) + strlen(two) + 1;
char *str3 = malloc(length * sizeof(char));
snprintf(str3, length, "%s%s", one, two);      
 // write more code that uses str3
free(str3);
 // now don't uses `str3`'s allocated memory
```

Comment: +1, and a symbolic gift from me: ↑

Comment: "Hello " already have a space. You need to do "%s%s" and remove one of the + 1 's

Comment: @Espen yes you are correct, I should correct  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how I feel about `sprintf` but hey, it works... One nitpick: if you are going to tell someone to call `malloc` then please be sure to *always* remind them that they also need to call `free` as well.

Comment: @NikBougalis yes that's the way so I added a link for malloc function. ..also I should  use snprintf instead sprintf  to avoid buffer overflow ..but I keep answer simple here.

Comment: The problem is that people won't read the link. They'll just copy your code and only make the minimum amount of changes necessary to get it to compile in their program. And while we can't stop people from shooting themselves in the foot, we can at least put a big "DON'T SHOOT HERE" sign on it.

Comment: @NikBougalis ha ha ... you are correct ... and because of copy-past  one more question on SO :)

Comment: @NikBougalis Added your suggestion thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Read a book about C.

```
str3 = malloc(strlen(one) + strlen(two) + 1) ; // +1 for the 0 terminator
strcpy(str3, one) ;
strcat(str3, two) ;
...
free(str3) ;   // frees allocated space when you are finished.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<char> v;
v.insert(v.end(), one, one + strlen(one));
v.insert(v.end(), two, two + strlen(two));
v.push_back('\0');
str3 = v.data();
```

Answer (score 1):

String literals like `"Hello"` are stored in read-only memory, so you need to copy them somewhere where they can be modified.

So you must first allocate memory where the strings are to be stored. A simply char array will do. Then use strcpy() and strcat() to copy the string literals into that array.